# How to configure redirects to url without trailing slash in nginx?

Tags: nginx

i need to make a of such a redirect:

```
domain.com/test/ (301) => domain.com/test
```

for this I used the following record:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

But there is a nuance, in pagination i have such links a redirect is performed for them too:

```
domain.com/category/?page=1&view=grid (301) => domain.com/category?page=1&view=grid
domain.com/category/?page=2&view=grid (301) => domain.com/category?page=2&view=grid
...
```

I wish there were no redirects for such links.

Can this be done through nginx or is it better then to do it in the site script ?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Also tried a this:

```
if ($query_string = "") {
   rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

but I don’t know if this is a good record ?

Comment: Do you mean that `if ($query_string = "") ...` didn't work?

Comment: @MichaelHampton
this works if i put it in a block ```server {...}```
And I would like to make sure that using such a condition is the right solution.
It's just that this article confuses me
[If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil)

Comment: The article says it is perfectly OK, which it is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton

Thanks, could you clarify a little.
Do you mean what is written - «The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are return, rewrite».
But I don't understand this sentence a little.
It's all good if inside ```if {...}``` there is ```return or rewrite``` ?
Or if inside the block ```location {...}``` there is ```return or rewrite``` ?

Comment: You are going to put this in your `location` so that doesn't really matter. But it is safe either way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton
No, I'll leave it in the ```server {...}``` block.
Ok thanks for the help. =)